# casper js how can i pass varibales from one homade function to another

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

okay so i have started building my own modules to use in casperjs i have come to a point where i want to pass variable from one function to another here is what i have below

my modules -- functions

```
exports.accdata = function(accnum, amnum) {
    var accountnumber = casper.fetchText('div.arabic:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(' + accnum + ') > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)');
    var amountwithtype =casper.fetchText('div.arabic:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(' + amnum + ') > td:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)');
    var redir = accountnumber.substr(1);
    var split = amountwithtype.split (' '); 
    var amount = split[0];
    var type = split[1];
};

exports.job = function (in1, in2){
    console.log(in1);
    console.log(in2);
};
```

and then how i am trying to pass is my casperjs script

```
casper.then(function(){
   universe.accdata("3", "3");
   universe.job(amount, type);
});
```

i am very new and really need help on how to set functions to pass data from on and another

Answer (score 0):

Your `accdata` function is just setting a bunch of variables then not using them. The simplest solution is to put both functions into one but another solution might be to return an object from your first function and pass it as a parameter to the second function.

```
exports.accdata = function(accnum, amnum) {
    return {
        accountnumber: casper.fetchText('div.arabic:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(' + accnum + ') > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)'),
        amountWithType: casper.fetchText('div.arabic:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(' + amnum + ') > td:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)'),
        ...
    };
};

exports.job = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    universe.job(universe.accdata("3", "3"));
});
```

Comment: i dont understand how data is going to be the specific input for universe job

Comment: ie get the amount and type from other function

Comment: You really shouldn't post multiple comments in a row like that. It works because the `accdata` function RETURNS those values. If you don't understand how to return values from a function, I suggest learning more about Javascript before trying to do anything in CasperJS.